# Actionscript 3 - Playing Textbox Animation in Movieclip [repeat]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textbox, movieclip

So I've got a movieclip, I've got another movieclip in that so I can tween it.

I've got the following code

```
 animText.displayedText.info_txt.text="YOU LICKED A TOILET BRUSH";
 animText.gotoAndPlay(1);
```

It starts from frame 1 each time the code is called...

but, if you call the code twice, a few seconds after the 1st...
it doesn't start from the beginning, but instead just ignores the second one.

Surely, since there is a gotoAndPlay && changing the text, it should start again.

Comment: i don't know your movieclips structure but maybe some of the childs of animText are animated too? perhaps you should make the gotoAndPlay(1) in a child of animText too, on displayedText or info_text. It is just an idea.

Comment: Try making what I said above and see if you could get it working :P